# Binomial coefficient after expansion.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

What is the coefficient of $x^7$ in the expansion of $(1-x-x^2+x^3)^6$ ?

Comment: Use the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: Brother I don't know multinomial theorem. How can I solve it using binomial?

Comment: @Adarsh: The multinomial theorem is obtained by just using the binomial theorem repeatedly to evaluate $(p+q+r+s)^n$ as (for instance) $(((p+q)+r)+s)^n$.

Comment: Ohoo, got that sir, will do some questions by this method. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the *fastest* way to compute this, after observing that $1$ and $-1$ are both obviously roots of $1-x-x^2+x^3$, and that $(1-x)(1+x)=1-x^2$,  is to write $1-x-x^2+x^3=(1-x^2)(1-x)$ so that
$$
  (1-x-x^2+x^3)^6 = (1-x^2)^6 (1-x)^6
  = \biggl(\sum_{i\geq0}(-1)^i\binom6ix^{2i}\biggr)
    \biggl(\sum_{j\geq0}(-1)^j\binom6jx^j\biggr).
$$
The coefficient of $x^7$ can only involve odd indices $j$; more precisely it comes from the terms with $(i,j)\in\{(1,5),(2,3),(3,1)$}, and is equal to
$$
 +\binom61\binom65-\binom62\binom63+\binom63\binom61 = 6\times6-15\times20+20\times6 = -144.
$$

Comment: Sir please explain me the last part. How you put the respective signs in binomial coefficients?

Comment: Oh I got that. Silly question sorry. :P thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

Just observe that 
$$
(1-x-x^2+x^3)^6 = (x+1)^6 (x-1)^{12}.
$$
The rest is easy.

Comment: Is this factorization Natural? Obvious? Easy to guess? (Irrespective of all that, +1)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It's obvious that $1$ is a root. Once this is noted, the factorization follows.

Comment: I'm not able to solve it further. Please guide me how to get the coefficient of x^7. And how did you observed its factors?

Comment: @GitGud : Yes.. It does follow :) whatever may be the case i like this :) :)

Comment: @Adarsh : what powers of $x$ in $(x-1)^{12}$ do you need to look into to get $x^7$ when multiplied with some power of $x$ in $(x+1)^6$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: brother I've already multiplied the binomial coefficient of zeroth term to binomial coefficient of 12th term from (x+1)^6 and (x-1)^12 resp. Is I'm doing right.?

Comment: why are you doing that :O you do not have to do all that... you do not have to know what is coefficient of say $x^8$ in $(x-1)^{12}$ you only need to know what are all coefficients of $x^i : 0\leq i \leq 7$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: bro how'll I approach the answer then? I know the coefficients. What next?

Comment: @Adarsh : I guess you got it from Marc van Leeuwen's answer... :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: yes brother, I got that. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the multinomial theorem, here:
$$
(a+b+c+d)^n
  = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + k_4 = n}
         \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4} a^{k_1} b^{k_2} c^{k_3} d^{k_4}
$$
The multinomial coefficient is here:
$$
\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4}
  = \frac{n!}{k_1! \, k_2! \, k_3! \, k_4!}
$$
Now you need to figure out which combinations of terms give the required power of $x$.

Comment: he said he do not know multinomial theorem.. By which i believe he is not allowed to use that (at this time at least )